# dojo.query not working for attribute selector that includes a tilde (~) character

Tags: dojo, css-selectors

I need to select a link node given its url. Using an attribute selector works quite well except for a few rare cases when the url has a tilda. I have no control over the link urls. Here is an example:

```
<script>
dojo.ready(function() {
    var node = dojo.query('a[href="http://abc.com/~123"]')[0];
    console.debug(node);
    node = dojo.query('a[href="http://abc.com/_123"]')[0];
    console.debug(node);
});
</script>
...
<body>
    <a href="http://abc.com/~123">link 1&lt;/a>
    <a href="http://abc.com/_123">link 2&lt;/a>
</body>
```

This prints:

```
undefined
<a href="http://abc.com/_123">
```

I looked at the level 3 selectors [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors) and didn't find anything on the tilde character being unsupported for attribute selector values which are just CSS strings.

Help!

Comment: tagged as a regression.  thanks for reporting this
http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/10651

Comment: Have you tried escaping the tilda? If it works with, for example, a backslash escape it will be relatively simple to manipulate the string in your URL query. Also, IIRC I think I encountered a similar issue with URL's that included an ampersand (not in the parameters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to have been fixed in 1.6 http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/10651